# Display SharePoint 2013 List RowCount in HTML after Query

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, caml-query

I am new to CAML queries and javascript but I would like to display a result from a SharePoint list query in HTML.  My list has approximately 300 total rows and I would like to get a row count when the Title field contains certain text to display in HTML.  The result would be text on the page that reads "There are x records that begin with ..."

My query seems to work but I don't know how to get the query to run on page load to display.

```
<View><Query><Where><BeginsWith><FieldRef Name='Title' /><Value Type='Text'>AFI</Value></BeginsWith></Where></Query></View>
```

Once I get this sorted out I would like to also have a few more queries to get the row counts of different query conditions.
"Rows that begin with ABC - xx"
"Rows that begin with 123 - xx"
and so on...

UPDATE:
Here is where I am right now and getting Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier and Invalid or unexpected token

```
<script src="/sites/AFA1/SiteAssets/Scripts/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/sites/AFA1/SiteAssets/Scripts/jquery.SPServices.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    getListItems(webUrl,listTitle) 
{
var webUrl = '/sites/AFA1/PMS'
var listTitle = 'Milestone%200%20DataSheet'
var viewXml = '<View><Query><Where><BeginsWith><FieldRef Name='Title' /><Value Type='Text'>AFI</Value></BeginsWith></Where></Query></View>';
    var url = webUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('"+listTitle+"')/items"; 
    var queryPayload = {  
               'query' : {
                      '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.CamlQuery' }, 
                      'ViewXml' : viewXml  
               }
    };

    return $.ajax({
           url: url,
           method: "POST",
           data: JSON.stringify(queryPayload),
           headers: {
              "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
              "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
              "content-type": "application/json; odata=verbose"
           }
     });
}
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this script to get items from list with CAML. You can use the data   result object to get the count etc.

```
function getListItems(webUrl,listTitle) 
{
    var viewXml = '<View><Query><Where><BeginsWith><FieldRef Name='Title' /><Value Type='Text'>AFI</Value></BeginsWith></Where></Query></View>';
    var url = webUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listTitle + "')/getitems"; 
    var queryPayload = {  
               'query' : {
                      '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.CamlQuery' }, 
                      'ViewXml' : viewXml  
               }
    };

    return $.ajax({
           url: url,
           method: "POST",
           data: JSON.stringify(queryPayload),
           headers: {
              "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
              "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
              "content-type": "application/json; odata=verbose"
           }
     });
}
```

Comment: Thanks Danny.  What would be the best way to fire off the function automatically when the page loads? I've only used buttons to start the functions before.

Comment: Check this: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: I can't seem to get anything to post back.  I'd include my code but I've deleted everything out of frustration.

Comment: I got my example from: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/134860/rest-api-in-sharepoint-query-specific-list-url/134886#134886 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26884647/using-rest-to-fetch-sharepoint-view-items

Comment: Once I get a working sample I will be able to get the rest going but I keep getting errors